# Can insurance for two [couple?] be used for one traveller?

Tags: safety, insurance

I'm based in the UK and my OH and I frequently travel around Europe - normally we get yearly European travel insurance for a 'couple' and that covers us both.

However, this year I plan to travel (alone) to the USA - is it worth getting worldwide insurance for two so we only need one insurance plan, or will the fact that it is for two people invalidate it if I travel alone?

I get the feeling this might be down to the discretion of individual insurers, so that would be my next port of all, but wondered first if any seasoned travellers had any advice.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need an insurance plan for two people if you are travelling alone?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer - we normally get a yearly policy. I'm wondering if a worldwide version of that yearly policy would cover me on my own.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to be sure would be to check the wording of the actual policy, or to check with the insurance company, however I would be very surprised if you were NOT covered when travelling alone.

I also have annual travel insurance, and a quick check of the policy document shows that it does cover adults (but not children!) when travelling alone, even if covered under a family policy.

You may also wish to check that your policy is suitable for travel to the US. Many policies aimed at other parts of the world have limits that are lower than may be required in the US, especially for medial fees. Given you normally travel in Europe you're probably OK, but it would be worth checking.